# Install Overlapping Marker Spiderfier for Leaflet with React

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, markerspiderfier

I am new to React. I try to use the npm module overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet in a react project.

I follow the instruction at https://www.npmjs.com/package/overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet so I do `npm install -S overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet` and then `import OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier from 'overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet';` in my project.

I then do `var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(this.map);`  but I get :

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError):
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8_overlapping_marker_spiderfier_leaflet**.OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier is not a constructor

Do you know how I could solve this error. Do you think I could rather use the minified js to use this plugin? How so?

Answer (score 7):

[`overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet) doesn't export anything in an ES6 compatible way. But it could be directly imported as a file from the library's dist folder:

```
import "overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet/dist/oms";
const OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier = window.OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier;
```

Example

```
import React from "react";
import {
  withLeaflet,
  MapLayer
} from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import "overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet/dist/oms";
const OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier = window.OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier;

class Spiderfy extends Component {

  componentDidMount(props) {
    const { map } = props.leaflet;
    const oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
    //...
  }

  //...
}
```

[This demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fro5up) demonstrates how to integrate `overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet` into [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/).

Comment: Actually you did a great job, thank you a lot, it worked for me, Am using react-leaflet.